# Copy rows in MySQL table multiple times and adding additional column

Tags: php, mysql, database, datatables, phpmyadmin

I have created  MySQL table in database. Table name is  products and the columns are( prodict_id(pk) product_name and pack_size) as shown in the figure below.

What I want to do is , copy all the rows in the table and add additional information in additional column called (buyer_name) so each product is associated with a specific buyer which makes it unique

[image: mysqltable]
Is there a way I can achieve this using query? Where I can give a list of buyers and it attaches it to all rows in table?

p.s I have almost 700 rows in my table and I have 12 buyers, so if I do it manually, it will consume too much time

Comment: Where are those buyer details kept in a table?

Comment: buyer details are actually saved in a table called buyers . Just for the sake of simplicity I was assuming them to be inserted manually in the case above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment your buyer details are in a table and you want to map each product with each of the buyer then you can write your insert query like below:

```
insert into newtable
select t1.*, t2.buyername from products t1 join buyers t2
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e25f76587c23fef6556e6f511b6517e)

You can use where clause also to filter some results from either of the table.

Comment: perfect! that is what I was exactly looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: You welcome. Please upvote if it is as per your expectation

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to automate the data insertion from product table to buyer table. How about, if you select that fetches all the buyers first and then you insert into buyer table.
It can be based on subquery where insert is the outer one and select is the nested one.

Good luck !